# laravel 5.4 php artisan make:auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have created the `laravel 5.4` fresh pack and configure the database connection afterwards

I ran the terminal command

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I am trying to login with correct credential but it's again redirect to login url?
I had check in `HomeController __construct() Auth::user()` return empty

Comment: Is that file the login controller?

Comment: @SapneshNaik yes is there

Comment: Does your authentication work or not? Because I just checked and this is normal, my function inside the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait is also empty, you should test to see if it's working or not first.

Comment: @OmarTarek It's not working i give correct credential and submit the form and watch network in developer tools, the login url status code was 302 and home url showed 302

Comment: Then you have to re-write your question, because as far as this question is concerned, there's nothing wrong with your 'authenticated' function.

Comment: @OmarTarek Ok. can you help then why it's again redirect to login after authenticated also?

Comment: no login error ?

Comment: first try to log using wrong username and password .. then if an error pops up try again with the correct credentials .. then tell us if it redirects you to the login page with no errors showing ..

Comment: @Demonyowh i tried that way also but same problem

Comment: how about the wrong username and password ? does it shows error ?

Comment: @Demonyowh yes it's showing `These credentials do not match our records.`

Answer (score 0):

This is intended. The method `authenticated` is called after the user successfully logs in. Though this method is called by `sendLoginResponse`. This method is left there for users to extend and modify to add additional checks if needed, like email confirmation, ban status etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. I forgot to add the `protected $table = 'users';` and `protected $primaryKey = 'userId';` in `User model` sorry for the inconvenient. Thanks for the your's time.